# Why would dm_exec_requests not show all active processes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I was running a delete on a table that was taking a while (several minutes) and I wanted to see what other process were being impacted.  Here is the query I ran to check:

```
SELECT  er.session_id,
        CAST(GETDATE()-er.start_time as time) [RunTime],
        er.command,
        t1.text [CommandText],
        er.blocking_session_id,
        t2.text [BText]
FROM master.sys.dm_exec_requests er
CROSS APPLY master.sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) AS t1
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 sql_handle
    FROM master.sys.sysprocesses
    WHERE spid = er.blocking_session_id
    AND sql_handle > 0
) p2
OUTER APPLY master.sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p2.sql_handle) t2
```

The oddity is that the "delete" process showed up as a blocking two other processes (queries).  I could see the session_id of the delete process, as well as the text of the delete statement.

But the "delete" process itself didn't show up in the dm_exec_requests result set.

I tried it again without the CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT * FROM master.sys.dm_exec_requests
```

And it still didn't show up.

Is that not the correct view to use?  Why wouldn't the delete, (which was active and running) show up as an executing request?

Comment: Is it possible that the delete was done in an explicit transaction, had finished, but the commit hadn't yet been issued?

Comment: @Ben Thul, I don't think so.  I had manually executed the delete statement through SSMS, and it was still running (according to the application) for several minutes before and after I queried the dm_exec_requests view.

Comment: Ben is right. Not committed transaction may block other processes, but it may not show up in sys.dm_exec_requests as it shows only active processes. Try to see what's going on in Profiler and sysprocesses

Comment: @Anton, Thanks.  Since SSMS was still had the "Executing Query ..." message, would this suggest that the delete was itself being blocked by another process?  Otherwise, wouldn't it count as active?